# PowerShell Error: Import-CSV Cannot Open File

Tags: csv, powershell

My PowerShell code is tripping some strange error codes, which I have thoroughly searched for to no avail.

I am trying to create a script that calculates some basic statistics for a number of CSV files, which seems to work until I try to create and populate new columns.

The error code I'm getting is:

> Import-Csv: Cannot open file "C:\zMFM\Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo".
> At C:\zMFM\StatsDebug.ps1:46 Char:21
>
> +$STATS2 = Import-CSV <<< $STATS
>
> +CategoryInfo : OpenError (:) [Import-Csv], FileNotFoundException
>
> +FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure.Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand at C:\zMFM\statsdebug.ps1:55 char:20

That's followed by an error using a null expression, but I assume fixing this problem with Import-Csv will in turn fix that error. Here's my code, any help would be great, thanks!

```
$i = 1
#$colSTDDEV = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn StdDev,([double])
$colVZA = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn VZA,([double])
#$colVAZ = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn VAZ,([double])

While ($i -le 211) {

#Set the variable to the filename with the iteration number
$filename = "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\fixed20dSum550Output$i.csv"


#Check to see if that a file with $filename exists. If not, skip to the next iteration of $i. If so, run the code to collect the 

statistics for each variable and output them each to a different file
If (Test-Path $filename) {


#Calculate the Standard Deviation
#First get the average of the values in the column
$STDEVInputFile = Import-CSV $filename

#Find the average and count for column 'td'
$STDEVAVG = $STDEVInputFile | Measure-Object td -Average | Select Count, Average
$DevMath = 0

# Sum the squares of the differences between the mean and each value in the array
Foreach ($Y in $STDEVInputFile) {
$DevMath += [math]::pow(($Y.Average - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)

#Divide by the number of samples minus one
$STDEV = [Math]::sqrt($DevMath / ($STDEVAVG.Count-1))

}

#Calculate the basic statistics for column 'td' with the MEASURE-OBJECT cmdlet
$STATS = Import-CSV $Filename |
Measure-Object td -ave -max -min

#Append the standard deviation variable to the statistics array and add the value

$STATS2 = Import-CSV $Stats
$VZA = $filename.VZA
#$VAZ = $filename.VAZ #COMMENTED FOR DEBUGING


#$STATS2.Columns.Add($colSTDDEV) #COMMENTED FOR DEBUGING
#$STATS2[0].StdDev = $STDEV #COMMENTED FOR DEBUGING


$STATS2.Columns.Add($colVZA)
$STATS2[0].VZA = $VZA


#$STATS2.Columns.Add($colVAZ) #COMMENTED FOR DEBUGING
#$STATS2[0].VZA = $VAZ #COMMENTED FOR DEBUGGING

#Export the $STATS file containing everything you need in the correct folder


Export-CSV -notype "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\20dSum550Statistics.csv"

}
$i++
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$STDEVInputFile = Import-CSV $filename
...
$STATS = Import-CSV $Filename |
  Measure-Object td -ave -max -min
# $STATS here will be type [GenericMeasureInfo], so you cannot use this as a filename.

$STATS2 = Import-CSV $Stats
# Are you trying to import $filename a third time here? You can't use $Stats because it's a [GenericMeasureInfo] object, not a [string].
```

Based on your code, it looks like you're trying to import a CSV with a filename of type `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo]`. Filenames are strings. Also, why are you importing `$filename` twice? Would recommend importing it once, then operating off of the variable you saved it to.

Would also recommend changing your while loop to `1..211 | ForEach-Object`. That way you won't have to worry about whether `$i` is less than or equal to your static number. Not a huge deal, but would make the code a little more readable.

**TL;DR**

`Import-CSV $Stats` is the problem. `$Stats` is not a valid filename, so you can't open/import it.

Comment: Oh, so changing the word 'STATS' to something else should fix the problem? I'll try it out in a few minutes when I'm back at my desk and report if that fixed it or not.

Comment: No, the problem is that you are storing `Measure-Object td -ave -max -min` into variable `$STATS`, and then you immediately try to open a CSV using `$STATS` as a filename when it is not a filename at all.

Comment: When you pipe something to `Measure-Object`, the result is an object of type `[GenericMeasureInfo]`, which you can't use as a filename.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Instead of immediately trying to view $STATS as a CSV, I first exported it as a CSV file and then re-imported it so the filetype will allow for columns to be added. It seems to have worked. Thanks.